# Angular using vm instead of $scope

Tags: angularjs

I try to use vm. But sometimes it working but sometimes it not.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl as profile">
   <div class="profile-box">
        <h4 class="m-b-0">{{ profile.name }}</h4>
        <p class="text-muted"> {{profile.username }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Profile', profileCtrl]);

 function profileCtrl($scope, $state, Profile) {
    const vm = this;
    Profile.get((resp)=> {
        vm.profile = resp.user;
    });
 }
```

How can I make it working to use `vm`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key line here is:

```
vm.profile = resp.user;
```

The proper way to reference this in your view would now be:

```
{{profile.profile.name}}
```

The first `profile` references your controller (from `ProfileCtrl as profile`) and the second your `profile` object within that controller (from `vm.profile = resp.user;`)

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl as profile">` to `<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl as vm">` and use it in view like `vm.profile.prop`